# Python memory-efficient read csv and parse fields

Tags: python, csv, memory-efficient

I'm trying to extract information from a .csv file and do some analysis. The file is not very large (but may be much larger in the future) currently this size of the csv file is 23MB. With Columns as:

```
SessionID    ActivityDate    ActivityID    ActivityType    InputValue    UserID    UserTitle
```

The analysis functions I'm writing don't need all of them, function A many just need columns "SessionID" and "ActivityDate" and function B may just need "ActivityID", "ActivityType" and "InputValue". How should I design so that I can avoid reading the file multiple times? I basically can think of two methods:

1. use a "readCSV" method that can return a dictionary object which contains all the columns and each column's corresponding values. Then for each function I just give different lists of values required by different functions.

[image]

But in this way I'll have to execute all the functions inside this "readcsv" function to avoid multiple file reading.

2. make this analysis a class so that this file can be read and the **init** part, different column can be this class's different variables. Then I only have to read once and set the each variable (column) of the class their corresponding values. But the problem here is won't this a waste of memory? Store all the values inside the class that I may not use for a long time; also, this is a analysis script and so far I don't see the point of make this a "class". There's no interactions between it with others (if any).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: 23 MB is next to nothing - how much larger do you expect the file to become? If it's going to go into gigabytes, then maybe a database is the most promising solution. Otherwise, just read that thing into memory and be done with it.

Comment: Just use `pandas.read_csv`. I don't see any problem here. Are you concerned about memory usage, or memory leaks in the read_csv()?  For saving memory, use pandas Categorical variables wherever possible rather than string, userid, zipcode etc.

Comment: @TimPietzcker this as I was told, is just some sample file to test performance, the larger file can go to gigabytes for sure or even larger.

Comment: @smci I'm not using pandas but csv DictReader. I'm more concerned about the memory usage.

Comment: @TimPietzcker If for now I just read all staff into memory, I assume i should use a global value for the file content instead of using a class ?

Comment: @JudyJiang I recommend you use pandas to get better memory usage. You don't need DictReader. Don't store strings as strings - use categorical variables wherever possible. (Also read about pandas being able to use HDFS if your file is too large for memory).

Comment: @smci OK I'll change to pandas. It seems more clean. Thanks!

Comment: Also look at the doc for [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) options, in particular the on-the-fly `compression` and `converters`.